# Finding recent information

Tags: discussion, old-questions

Just now, I was looking at drill-down on Android. So I googled "drill down android site:stackoverflow.com". The top hits were [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958560/implementing-drilldown-navigation-in-android-app-ui) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286871/how-do-i-implement-drill-down-listview), both from 2010. The next one was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887729/best-method-for-true-drill-down-navigation-in-navigation-drawer) from 2014. After that, there were hits from 2012 and 2011.

The problem is that mobile changes pretty often, so at first glance, I have no idea if the answers are or are not still current. I could do a date-limited search, and that might turn up something interesting. But what I want is not actually a particular date range; I want something that tends to prefer more-recent information. Google seems to do the opposite -- the longer a question has been around, the more upvotes and links it has, and, therefore, the higher its rank.

As a site, does SO have a way to address this issue? And as a user, I'm curious if others have found a way to deal with it that they like.

Comment: If you know EXACTLY what you're looking for (aka don't need the fuzzy matching Google does) isn't the [advanced site search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) all you need?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=drill%20down%20android%20.

Comment: @rene perhaps OP isn't aware Stack Overflow got internal search mechanism.

Comment: @ShadowWizard are you going to answer every comment of mine that ends in a question mark with responses like that? If yes, it is going to be a long day then ;)